# Select strings from list where logical value is TRUE

Tags: r, logical-operators, stringi

I would like to extract duplicated strings from a list. As, the unique function does not work on non-numerical data, I used the stringi package with the stri_duplicated function to obtain logical values (TRUE or FALSE). I would like to extract the strings that are duplicated from the list (the strings for which stri_duplicated reports a TRUE).

Here a minimal example:

```
ex1 <- c("SE1", "SE2", "SE5", "SE2")
dupl <- stri_duplicated(ex1)

> dupl
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean `unique` does not work for non-numeric. Did you try `unique(ex1)`?

Comment: I was wrong. I tried it once more and now it worked just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In base-R there is

```
duplicated(ex1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

if you want to extract the duplicated items

```
ex1[duplicated(ex1)]
[1] "SE2"
```

Comment: If the downvoter cares to comment why they think this is a poor answer, I would be happy to address it.